# dataframe one row save to excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlwings

i'd like to ask a simple question. I want to save the last row of a dataframe to an excel sheet last rows without colname of dataframe.

```
Dataframe:
  date        Name  Age
2019/10/1     Kate   18
2019/10/2     Jim    20
2019/10/3     James  23
```

```
excel sheet:
  date       Name  Age
2019/9/29    Rose   18
2019/9/30    Eva    20
```

I want to add dataframe values to excel last row,something like this

```
excel sheet new:
  date       Name  Age
2019/9/29    Rose   18
2019/9/30    Eva    20
2019/10/1    Kate   18
2019/10/2    Jim    20
2019/10/3    James  23
```

```
code:
app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False)
wb=app.books.open(path_xl)
sht=wb.sheets[sht_name]
rng=sht.range("A1")
last_rows=rng.current_region.rows.count
sht.range('A'+str(last_rows+1)).value=df.values
```

but the result saved in excel sheet is wrong, i dont know why

Comment: Hi! Assuming you data is in a Pandas dataframe, you could try df.tail(1).to_excel("output.xlsx") . tail(1) grabs the end of the dataframe. see, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: `df.iloc[-1:, :].to_excel('file_name.xlsx', header=False)`

Comment: many thanks, i want to save df.iloc[-1:, :] to the last row of an excel sheet. can to_excel function do?